# Is there any way to download the audio manipulated using Muses Library (WebAudio API)?

Tags: javascript, file, audio, download, web-audio-api

So basically this is the application: [Muses Demo](https://rawcdn.githack.com/samuraicorpse/muses/main/test.html)

And here is the GitHub Repo for it : [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/samuraicorpse/muses)

The audio can be played in the browser after some manipulation (Eg: Panning and Volume).

But I have no clue how to download the processed audio file. The library provides `play()`, `pause()` and so on functions but does not have an `export()` or `download()` function.

I've added a button 'Download'. How shall I proceed?

```
const audioTrack = new muses.AudioTrack("path/to/audio.mp3", audioContext);

//this works
audioTrack.play();

//i have tried to do this but obviously, getData() is not a function in the library
audioTrack.getData().then((audioData) => {
  const audioBlob = new Blob([audioData], { type: "audio/mpeg" });
  const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
  downloadLink.download = "audio.mp3";
  downloadLink.click();
});
```